# Can't cancel doInBackground process in AsyncTask even using cancel method

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have declared instance of FileUploadTask which extends AsyncTask in onCreate() method

```
                FileUploadTask uploadTask= null;
```

and  executes the background method by following code

```
                    public class UploadFiles implements OnClickListener{

                    ....

                    if(SOTCNetStat.chkConnectionStatus(UploadResult.this)){
                                uploadTask=new FileUploadTask();
                                uploadTask.execute("");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(UploadResult.this, getResources().getString(R.string.Text_CheckNetworkConnections) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                              
                            }
                    ....

                }
```

Having a cancel button to cancel the background process

```
                cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Log.d(TAG,"cancel button clicked.....");
                            //FileUploadTask uploadTask= new FileUploadTask();
                            if(uploadTask!=null)
                            {
                                Log.d(TAG,"click event null checking....");
                                uploadTask.cancel(true);
                            }


                        }

                }
```

In FileUploadTask class declared a boolean to check the running status

```
        public class FileUploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        ....
            boolean isRunning=true;
```

The doInBackground method

```
    @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            for(int i=0; i<fp.size(); i++){
                index = i+1;

                if(isCancelled() && !isRunning)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Cancel 1 Condition Checked ["+i+"]");
                    Log.d(TAG,"doInBackground canceled");
                    break;

                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Cancel 1 Canceled ["+i+"]");
                }

                file1 = new File(fp.get(i));

                String urlString = Constants.UPLOAD_URL;

                try {

                    Log.e("doInBackground", "urlString: " + urlString);

                    Log.e("doInBackground", "domainPref: " + domainName);

                    urlString = urlString.replace("domain", URLEncoder.encode(domainName, "UTF-8"));

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }




                try {

                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
                    FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file1);

                    ProgressMultipart reqEntity = new ProgressMultipart(new ProgressListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            //publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) file1.length() ) * 100));

                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize ) * 100));
                        }
                    });

                    reqEntity.addPart("userfile", bin1);
                    if(getIntent().hasExtra("show_id"))
                    {
                        //String showId = getIntent().getStringExtra("show_id");
                        reqEntity.addPart("mobileshow", new StringBody("1"));
                        reqEntity.addPart("show_ids", new StringBody(getIntent().getStringExtra("show_id")));
                    }
                    reqEntity.addPart("Filename", new StringBody(file1.getName()));
                    reqEntity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody("2"));
                    reqEntity.addPart("privateasset", new StringBody("true"));
                    reqEntity.addPart("uploadtype", new StringBody("Normal"));
                    reqEntity.addPart("version_num", new StringBody("1"));

                    totalSize = reqEntity.getContentLength();

                    post.setEntity(reqEntity);

                    System.err.println("post :"+post.toString());

                    //to be check the cancel operation
                    if(isCancelled() && !isRunning)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG,"Cancel 2 Condition Checked ["+i+"]");
                        Log.d(TAG,"File Uploading Cancelled in doInBackground method");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG,"Cancel 2 Canceled ["+i+"]");
                    }

                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

                    resEntity = response.getEntity();
                    response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                } 
    ....
    return response_str;
    }
```

and overloaded onCancelled methods

```
@Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG,"onCancelled() method called");
            super.onCancelled();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG,"onCancelled(String) method called");

            isRunning=false;


            this.cancel(true);

        }
```

I tried a lot and explored . Even using cancel method I can't able to stop the uploading process in background. Please any one give solutions to the problem
Some links i referred

http://www.technotalkative.com/cancel-asynctask-in-android/

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing how `AsyncTask` works. The `onCancelled()` method will only be called after `doInBackground()` is finished, similar to the `onPostExecute()` method. It is not called immediately after `uploadTask.cancel(true)` is called as you think it will be. The way you are using it, you have no need for `onCancelled()` methods or an `isRunning` variable (currently in your code `isRunning` is never changed to `false` and thus your `isCancelled()` check never works). Remove both the `onCancelled()` methods and the `isRunning` variable and your `AsyncTask` will work.

Comment: both are remove.But the upload completed without cancelling it

Comment: if(isCancelled()){ break; } within the for loop and same code before catch as I mentioned in the code. Then I removed both onCancelled() method.

Comment: There is something else going on. Your `client.execute()` call creates a separate thread (different from the one executing `donInBackground()`) and that separate thread updates the download status by calling periodically the `transferred()` method you passed to `reqEntity`. Apparently you cannot cancel this separate thread (such limitation needs to be verified in the API you are using, though). Using an AsyncTask is actually unnecessary here BTW.

Comment: If the `ProgressMultipart` doesn't allow cancelling progress, try using [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7411814/2241463) in your AsyncTask (with a few adaptations since you are going to read bytes and not lines) and add the `publishProgress()` call to it. You read the input stream in a loop and update the progress dialog as the stream is read, being able to check `isCancelled()` during the loop.

Comment: Note: I might be wrong about `client.execute()` creating a separate thread, but my suggestion is still valid.

Comment: yes u r right. stopped uploading except 1st in the Q.Then after request sent can't stop the response. Great suggestion Piovezan.

Answer (score 0):

check this, after canceling the asynctask write this condition.

```
if(asynctask.iscancel()){
break;
}
```

it may help for u. :)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html